# LinkedHashMap - get index of the inserted item

Tags: java, delphi

I need to implement in Java a code that was implemented long ago in Delphi, I'm trying to use LinkedHashMap (in Delphi was used TStringlist) because I need to get the index of the elements as they are inserted, the problem is that it is not working ...

Delphi

```
sIni:string;
sl, slProfs, slHoras, slDias, slAula: TStringlist;
slHoras := TStringlist(slProfs.Objects[p]);

  h := slHoras.indexOf(sIni);
  if h < 0 then 
  begin
    sl := TStringlist.Create;
    sl.sorted := true;
    for i := 1 to 7 do 
      sl.AddObject(IntToStr(i), TStringlist.Create);
    h := slHoras.AddObject(sIni, sl);
  end; 

  slDias := TStringlist(slHoras.Objects[h]);
  slAula := TStringlist(slDias.Objects[iDia - 1]);
```

implementation I'm trying to do in Java

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, List<String>>> slProfs = new LinkedHashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> sl = new LinkedHashMap<>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, List<String>>> slHoras = new LinkedHashMap<>();
HashMap<String,String> slAula = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List <String> slDias = new ArrayList<>();

if (h < 0) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        sl.put(i, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    slHoras.put(sIni, sl);
    indicesslHoras = new ArrayList<String>(slHoras.keySet()); // <== Set to List
    h = indicesslHoras.indexOf(sIni);
}
```

I can not get the object from position h 
using LinkedHashMap as it is done here :

```
slDias := TStringlist(slHoras.Objects[h]);
slAula := TStringlist(slDias.Objects[iDia - 1]);
```

The code in Delphi is implemented using a StringList inside another StringList with an index ...
Is this approach using LinkedHashMap the best one to transcribe this code to Java?

Comment: You are looking for an ordered dictionary. You can find one in the spring4d library

Answer (score 1):

The `LinkedHashMap` class guarantees that when you iterate through it, the elements are returned the same order you put them in, but it's a mistake to say that this is indexed. There is no 'indexOf' method and the only way to figure out the index is to iterate through the whole map which is slow and just not how it is intended.

From what I can find about TStringList, its object associated abilities is just lookup based. So, the java equivalent would simply be a `List<String>` for the strings and then presumably another `List<T>` of equal size with the associated objects. Lookups are O(n) (loop through the list until you find your record).

Comment: This is not how you do it. For best performance you need a dedicated class. The one spring4d does the job efficiently.